# What algorithm should be used to decide which lines to redraw when the screen refreshes?

Tags: objective-c, ios, drawing, cgpath

I made a simple iOS View based application which would let you draw and erase on the screen.
I am using an NSMutableArray to store already drawn paths.
and every time i switch the control to eraser from marker or vice versa , I add the current CGPath to the array and create a new one.

and every time in drawRect I redraw the array's paths with appropriate color depending on whether it was an eraser's path or marker's path

and draw the current one as well which is being draw as the touch moves.

Now I know that this is NOT AT ALL a good solution and would eat up a lot of RAM as the array size grows.
My array will already be containing redundant paths that actually go over points that are already colored with same color and would be unnecessarily be eating processor's time for doin it again and the memory as well.

Can anyone refer a better algorithm to save on the resources ?

Comment: Why do you believe it would eat up a lot of RAM?  Paths are cheap, they're just lists of points and operators.  Images are expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RAM wouldn't be your issue. Having solved this problem very recently, I can tell you that redrawing all the paths over again will start taxing the processor after a while. The way I solved this was to "rasterize" the paths to an image and just draw the image with the newest path on it. This seems to work well for any number of paths and scales well since the image size doesn't really change (size of the screen).

Let me know if you need a specific code example.

Comment: you mean that Everytime I will save the current screen as an image into an instance variable.
and draw the image on the screen in draw rec and keep drawing on the current path.
that would be a nice solution.
But tell me.. how much memory would a screen image take ?
hmmm .. 4 bytes [3 of color and 1 for opacity level ] X number of pixels.

Comment: That's about right. Remember though that you're only saving one image at a time, so it's not a big deal.

Comment: is there a method to that ? or I will have to run nested loops through the pixels ands save them ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/SbEBjCS7 I've put my algorithm here. You'll have to adapt it to your stroke array. Let me know if things are unclear.

Answer (score 5):

Don't just assume that you have a memory issue until you measure your app under Instruments and see that you do. Otherwise, you might end up putting in a lot of effort for little to no benefit.

Comment: See I may not be havin memory issues now but there will be many instances where, array size will be too  much.
and i will be redrawing it and erasing and redrawing again everytime the the touch moves.
Programs like Photoshop or GIMP or Paint .. they must be doin domething diff.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to deal with the graphic context of the layer.
For drawing new paths, just avoid from clearing the current graphics context before drawing. That way you can overlay the new draw over the current ones.
For erasing just clear by drawing in context with kCGBlendModeClear blendMode.

Comment: and How is that possible without taking an array and refreshing.
if I want to draw something ..that has to happen in drawRect and whenever drawrect is called ..i will lose all that is already there.
So i will hav e to save it. and since I saving various paths of eraser and marker. I will definitely need an array.
Can please elaborate your idea a bit more ?